# Unable to find pandoc location on macos Big Sur

Tags: pandoc

I installed pandoc on my machine using macos installer. But I am not being able to locate it. Plz see screenshot
[image]

As you can see we can chk its version, but why is the location saying as no such file/directory. Can I get some help on how to locate the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc reports the user data directory, which is the folder it checks when looking for custom templates, defaults files, filters, etc. The folder doesn't necessarily exist. You can create it by running `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/pandoc`.

If you are trying to find the location of the `pandoc` executable, run `which pandoc` instead.